# XSL Functions in Powershell/.NET Causing "Unexpected Token" Error

Tags: c#, .net, xml, powershell, xslt

I am trying to use the XSLT objects in .NET via Powershell.

I have the following lines in my XSL document

```
<xsl:variable name=""p"" select=""Objects/Object/Property[@Name='distrolists']""/>
<xsl:value-of select=""replace($p, 'oldtext', 'newtext')""/>
```

And I am configuring the XslCompiledTransform object as follows:

```
$xsltsettings = new-object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltSettings($true,$true)
$tr = new-object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
$tr.Load($xsl, $xsltsettings,$(New-Object System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver))
$results = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create("C:\output.html")
$tr.Transform($x,$results)
```

However, when I execute it, I get the following error:

```
Exception calling "Load" with "3" argument(s): "Unexpected token ',' in the expression.
replace( -->,<--  'oldtext', 'newtext')"
```

It looks like .NET is having some problems parsing the commas in the XSL functions. I'm pretty much at a loss on what is wrong with my XSL (or perhaps the processor is broken).

The end goal of this section is to take a \r\n delimited list of email addresses and display them by line with a `<br/>.`

Comment: `replace` is an XSLT 2.0 function, but XslCompiledTransform uses XSLT 1.0, so that function would not be supported.

Comment: Any .NET functionality that supports XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Take a look at Saxon-HE (http://saxon.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out by @Tim C:

> `replace` is an XSLT 2.0 function, but XslCompiledTransform uses XSLT 1.0, so that function would not be supported.

You should take a look at [Saxon-HE](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) if you need XSLT 2.0 functionality in .NET

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Tim C's first comment should have been an answer. Since you appear to be a member of the SO police force, please let me know how to ensure that the question is marked as answered without claiming credit for the answer, other than the way I did so.

Comment: Your post should have been a comment on the original question as it does not actually answer the question. If @Tim C comments answer the question they are in the wrong spot (ie: they should be provided in an answer with clear details).

Comment: Edited your post for an example of a proper answer that gives @Tim C credit but will also be useful for other users as it provides details. Hope that helps.